# Email attribute is invisible, in rails 4 with strong paramaters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my users controller i hav defined-

```
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
    end
```

In ticket template

Created by <%= @ticket.user.email %>
when I write ticket.user.name , it displays the name but when i write email, its invisible.

```
  class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :user
  end

  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
    validates :name, presence: true
  end
```

Comment: Does your `Ticket` table have the column `user_id`?

Comment: yes, user_id is there.

Comment: And what about your `ticket_params`? does that have `user_id`? I like to validate my models, like `ticket.rb` with `validates :user_id, presence: true`, that way when I'm testing the form, if a user is not getting saved with the object, the form won't submit and I know there is an error somewhere.

Comment: But then why name is getting displayed when i write "ticket.user.name ", Sorry i edited the question, hoping that you hav noticed it.

Comment: I assume the email didn't get saved? Go to your Command Line, type `rails c`, then find that user..maybe `User.first` if it's the first user...tell me if that user has an email attached to it

Comment: Yup, that was the problem,I was posting from 1st user in which email was nil... thank you so much :) :) :)

Comment: Glad we figured it out. Use that Command Line as much as you can! Cheers

Comment: @Justin Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the email didn't get saved? Go to your Command Line, type `rails c`, then find that user..maybe `User.first` if it's the first user...tell me if that user has an email attached to it